# Postgresql full text search on really short documents (filename)

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, ranking

I have a database of filenames in which I'm trying to search using PGs full text search facility. I'm running the search query on a table of filenames, the problem is that the ranking functions are not ranking the results as I'd like them to do. For the sake of argument, let's assume the schema looks like this:

```
create table files (
    id serial primary key,
    filename text,
    filename_ft tsvector
);
```

The query that I run looks something like this:

```
select filename, ts_rank(filename_ft, query)
from files, to_tsquery('simple', 'a|b|c') as query
where query @@ name_ft
order by rank desc limit 5;
```

This will return the 5 results with the highest rank. However, those search queries are coming from another process, and in most cases the queries have some 'garbage' in them. For instance, a query for 'a xxxx' might be executed, where xxxxx is just a bunch of other terms. In most cases this still returns the correct results, because the suffix is simply not in the database.

However, sometimes a query contains some extraneous information that screws with the ranking function. For instance, a query for 'a b c' will return a filename containing the tokens 'b c' as first result, and an exact match on 'a' as second result, my guess this is due to the fact the the first result contains a larger percentage of the actual search tokens.

In most cases (if not all) the most important token appears as the first token in the query, so my question is, is there a way to give the tokens in the query a weight?

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to give the tokens in the query a weight?

Yes, there is. See [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-textsearch.html); search for "weight".

Whether assigning weights is the right choice is another matter. It sounds to me like you really want to exclude some of the data from the inputs to `to_tsvector` in index creation and searching, so you just don't include that garbage in the index.

Comment: As far as I understand that documentation you can assign weights to lexemes in the tsvector, but I can't find anything about assigning weights to the query tokens. The extraneous data is not in the tsvectors, it's supplied in the query.